# KDB combine/join different table

Tags: join, kdb

How can i join two different table like

```
all_order_ask:([]ask:();ask_qty:();exchange_name_ask:())
all_order_bid:([]bid:();bid_qty:();exchange_name_bid:())
```

and get  =====>

```
final_order:ask:();ask_qty:();exchange_name_ask:();bid:();bid_qty:();exchange_name_bid:()
```

the two table have the same number of rows

Comment: If you're joining these two tables sideways, how will you ensure the alignment of the two?  Are they time-ordered? Shouldn't the bids and asks be joined based on some prevailing timestamp? Otherwise you're just arbitrarily aligning them

Comment: I sorted them before

Comment: Yes but the fact that they're both sorted still doesn't ensure that your alignment is correct. You could be joining later asks to earlier bids (aka future information). This sort of join should really be done as an asof (`aj`) join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use uj:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/uj/

```
all_order_ask uj all_order_bid
ask ask_qty exchange_name_ask bid bid_qty exchange_name_bid
-----------------------------------------------------------
q)
```

If your tables look similar like this:

```
all_order_ask
ask      ask_qty exchange_name_ask
----------------------------------
7.051033 8       bjd              
1.497004 3       lln              
2.400771 0       edg              
1.039355 7       lij              
2.353326 6       hon              
6.423479 4       ncp              
5.778177 6       gee              
2.193148 5       ijf              
1.66486  4       bbf              
4.784272 2       lmi              
all_order_bid
bid      bid_qty exchange_name_bid
----------------------------------
15.70605 2       pjbke            
10.93533 17      epjak            
7.040985 11      ekaaj            
14.19316 19      mpnan            
9.248942 17      nogel            
1.615466 18      holpj            
1.073589 16      kkfpn            
19.85822 13      pegin            
14.45499 8       jcgnm            
16.47223 0       dlhep
```

You can try this:
all_order_ask^all_order_bid

```
ask      ask_qty exchange_name_ask bid      bid_qty exchange_name_bid
---------------------------------------------------------------------
7.051033 8       bjd               15.70605 2       pjbke            
1.497004 3       lln               10.93533 17      epjak            
2.400771 0       edg               7.040985 11      ekaaj            
1.039355 7       lij               14.19316 19      mpnan            
2.353326 6       hon               9.248942 17      nogel            
6.423479 4       ncp               1.615466 18      holpj            
5.778177 6       gee               1.073589 16      kkfpn            
2.193148 5       ijf               19.85822 13      pegin            
1.66486  4       bbf               14.45499 8       jcgnm            
4.784272 2       lmi               16.47223 0       dlhep
```

Comment: I had already tried but it shifts the table : the bids start after the end of the asks

Comment: If your tables have time column, you should join ask and bid with time as a key column: (1!all_order_ask) uj 1!all_order_bid  , assuming first columns are time

Answer (score 3):

Since your two tables have the same number of rows, you should also be able to join your two tables horizontally using `,'` as follows:

```
q)final_order_ask:all_order_ask,'all_order_bid
q)final_order_ask
ask ask_qty exchange_name_ask bid bid_qty exchange_name_bid
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This throws me an error .. qpython.qtype.QException: b'length'                                                          
although they have the same number of rows